# Where do airports use 3-bar VASI for the visual glideslope?

Tags: airport, airport-lighting

What are some airports that have a 3-bar VASI system?  I am trying to find some locations to compare what the chart supplements say to the supplements for those with 2-bar VASI systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Runway 8 at [Albuquerque International Sunport Airport (KABQ)](https://skyvector.com/airport/ABQ/Albuquerque-International-Sunport-Airport) has a 3-bar VASI.

KABQ's [current Chart Supplement page](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1610/afdpdf/sw_309_15sep2016.pdf)<sup>1</sup> lists the VASI for Runway 8 as a `VASI(V6L)`: a 3 bar, 6 box VASI located on the left side of the runway. The airport diagram also depicts the VASI as a V<sub>3</sub>: a three-bar VASI. 
[image]

The VASI bars are also visible in aerial images, such as [here on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.0444263,-106.6145324,390m/data=!3m1!1e3):

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>The current Chart Supplement page will expire and this link will be broken. For future reference, the updated Chart Supplement page can be found elsewhere, such as on [this SkyVector page](https://skyvector.com/airport/ABQ/Albuquerque-International-Sunport-Airport).</sub>